# Spark Java 2.6.0 - Shutdown hook

Tags: spark-java

The docs for spark-java 2.6.0 mention that "Embedded Jetty is now fully configurable".

How do I go about configuring a shutdown hook via Spark 2.6.0?

I've overridden Jetty's Handler.doStop() method in the past, but I'm unclear how something equivalent is accomplished through the Spark framework.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you override `Handler.doStop()` in sparkjava:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String ...args) throws Exception {
        EmbeddedServers.add(EmbeddedServers.Identifiers.JETTY, (Routes routeMatcher, StaticFilesConfiguration staticFilesConfiguration, boolean hasMultipleHandler) -> {
            MatcherFilter matcherFilter = new MatcherFilter(routeMatcher, staticFilesConfiguration, false, hasMultipleHandler);
            matcherFilter.init(null);

            JettyHandler handler = new MyJettyHandler(matcherFilter);

            return new EmbeddedJettyServer((int maxThreads, int minThreads, int threadTimeoutMillis) -> new Server(), handler);
        });

        get("/hello", (req, res) -> {
            req.session(true);
            return "Hello World";
        });
    }
 }

class MyJettyHandler extends JettyHandler {

    public MyJettyHandler(Filter filter) {
        super(filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doStop() throws Exception {
        super.doStop();

        // your magic happens here.
    }
}
```

the code where i initialize the embedded jetty is taken from [sparkjava](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/2.6.0/src/main/java/spark/embeddedserver/jetty/EmbeddedJettyFactory.java#L39) itself, so i do not alter the behavior of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are searching for an answer for this for newer versions of Spark, here is a reference: http://sparkjava.com/documentation#stopping-the-server

Since URLs on the internet do not live for ever here is the qoute:

> By calling the stop() method the server is stopped and all routes are cleared.

And and example of how I use the code:

```
    public static void stopService(){
        stop();
        awaitStop();
    }
```

What is the usage of this? For example when you want to do a repeated test on the service clearing it and reinitializing it then this comes in handy,